# How to asynchronously load up multiple program indices in one process

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a large project file that consists of a website (front end/back end server), as well as 2 bots, a Twitch and a Discord bot that I have made in Node.js. I have a central file where I import all 3 indices, which is the file that I run in the node terminal. After the 3 files initiate, I need to fetch an array from my database, and then do something to it (that part is not important). But to do this, I would need to make sure that I have already connected to the database (mongodb), as well as have the bots initialized properly before I can proceed.

I have looked in to packages such as CronJob and ShellJS, but I am not sure if these would be the best and most efficient approaches.

This is all that I have in my `index.js` file (which is the file that gets ran in the node terminal)

```
require('./Bots/Bot Indices/discord');
require('./Bots/Bot Indices/twitch');
require('./Website/server');
```

Ideally, I would have completed the initialization of all three of these (callback, etc), so that I can be certain fetching from my database will not throw an error.

Comment: Make them export promises, don't use callbacks. Then you can simply use `Promise.all()` to make sure that all of them are initialised.

Comment: Assuming that all of the initialization happens at the top level of the module this is not trivial. This is equivalent to "import with side-effects," which is generally considered bad practice. Modules that have side-effects are difficult to test and integrate with other modules. The "correct" thing to do would be wrap the code in a method that can be called and notifies the caller when complete, then you can coordinate when things are ready, otherwise you're going to be dealing with non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I am not exporting the files as modules.

Comment: @Timesis That's not my point, you do not assign the "require" to a variable. This means that when you "require" your "Bots" and "server" they just do a bunch of stuff on their own. How are you to determine when they are finished "getting ready"? You can't and that's my point. Your modules should be exporting methods that can be called in your "index.js" so that it can pass in a callback, or wait for a promise to resolve, then you will be able to determine when everything is "ready."

Comment: @Timesis Jake is completely on the money here, you modules need to be self contained and ideally `called` to initialize. Those calls can then return `Promises` allowing you to correctly manage execution flow. It will also allow you to port functionality and test individual modules correctly.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger  + Bibberty, I see, I completely overlooked and misinterpreted what was happening under the hood, thank you for enlightening me.